# Getting resource error accessing Redis Q multiple times

Tags: java, android, redis, socketexception, jedis

This is my code used to access the value from redis Q.

```
Jedis jedis = null;
try
{
int maxActive = 1000;
int maxIdle = 5;
int minIdle = 1;
long maxWait = 5000;

JedisPoolConfig config = new JedisPoolConfig ();
config.setMaxActive (maxActive);
config.setMaxIdle (maxIdle);
config.setMinIdle(minIdle);
config.setMaxWait (maxWait);
config.setTestOnBorrow (false);
pool = new JedisPool (config, RedisServerURL) ;

jedis = pool.getResource();
jedis.getClient().setTimeoutInfinite();
redisQMesssage = jedis.rpop(RedisQ);
//my code           
}
catch (Exception e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
finally{
pool.returnResource(jedis); 
pool.destroy();
}
```

I have the above code in 3 worker threads. i'm calling the 3 worker thread for 40 times(totally).
Rarely 1/5 times i'm getting the error **"Could not get a resource from the pool(SocketTimeoutException:)"**

Stack trace is

```
redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool
at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:22)
at Workers.Worker1.met1(Worker1.java:124)
at Workers.Worker1.work(Worker1.java:108)
at org.gearman.impl.worker.WorkerConnectionController$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)  

Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:124)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:54)
at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.connect(BinaryJedis.java:1657)
at redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool$JedisFactory.makeObject(JedisPool.java:63)
at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1188)
at redis.clients.util.Pool.getResource(Pool.java:20)
... 6 more  

Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:119)
... 11 more
```

Please help me out.

Comment: In my Java App I'm using Jedis2.0.0.jar file and redis server version is 2.4.13. Is it making the problem?

Comment: did you solve it? could you post the solution?